# How to dynamically remove empty query parameters?

Tags: java, rest, http

I am sending some get query to an API that returns a **400 Bad request** when I send empty query parameters.

However, I do not know in advance which optional query parameters will be empty.
Apart from testing each optional parameter for emptyness, is there a simpler approach to dynamically remove empty parameters ?

Currently I am doing:

```
private URI getApiUrl(QueryParametersObject qpo) {
    String url = configBundle.getPropertyStr("some.api.url");
    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder
            .fromHttpUrl(url)
            .queryParam("mandatoryParam1", qpo.getMandatoryParam1())  // MANDATORY
            .queryParam("mandatoryParam2", qpo.getMandatoryParam2());  // MANDATORY
            
    if (!qpo.getOptionalParam1().isEmpty())
        builder.queryParam("optionalParam1", qpo.getOptionalParam1());
    if (!qpo.getOptionalParam2().isEmpty())
        builder.queryParam("optionalParam2", qpo.getOptionalParam2());
    if (!qpo.getOptionalParam3().isEmpty())
        builder.queryParam("optionalParam3", qpo.getOptionalParam3());
    return builder.build().encode().toUri();
}
```

It can become quite cumbersome when the number of optional query parameters grows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way to do this is to use a newer version of `spring-web`, like `5.3.4`, in which the class `UriComponentsBuilder` gets a new method `UriBuilder queryParamIfPresent(String name, Optional<?> value)` that you can use like this:

```
private URI getApiUrl(QueryParametersObject qpo) {
    String url = configBundle.getPropertyStr("some.api.url");
    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder
        .fromHttpUrl(url)
        .queryParam("mandatoryParam1", qpo.getMandatoryParam1())  // MANDATORY
        .queryParam("mandatoryParam2", qpo.getMandatoryParam2())  // MANDATORY
        .queryParamIfPresent("optionalParam1", Optional.of(qpo.getOptionalParam1()))
        .queryParamIfPresent("optionalParam2", Optional.of(qpo.getOptionalParam2()))
        .queryParamIfPresent("optionalParam3", Optional.of(qpo.getOptionalParam3()));
    return builder.build().encode().toUri();
}
```

Comment: `Optional.of` is throwing NullPointerException so it may be wrong solution

Answer (score 5):

Further enhancing the accepted answer by @l0r3nz4cc10

`Optional.ofNullable` would be a better approach !!!

```
private URI getApiUrl(QueryParametersObject qpo) {
    String url = configBundle.getPropertyStr("some.api.url");
    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder
        .fromHttpUrl(url)
        .queryParam("mandatoryParam1", qpo.getMandatoryParam1())  // MANDATORY
        .queryParam("mandatoryParam2", qpo.getMandatoryParam2())  // MANDATORY
        .queryParamIfPresent("optionalParam1", Optional.ofNullable(qpo.getOptionalParam1()))
        .queryParamIfPresent("optionalParam2", Optional.ofNullable(qpo.getOptionalParam2()))
        .queryParamIfPresent("optionalParam3", Optional.ofNullable(qpo.getOptionalParam3()));
    return builder.build().encode().toUri();
```