# why UriComponentsBuilder is ignoring null query params?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am trying to construct a url `UriComponentsBuilder`.

```
UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(BASE)
                .pathSegment("api")
                .pathSegment("v1")
                .queryParam("param1", userId) //userId in null
                .queryParam("param2",productId) //productId 12345
                .build().toUriString();
```

What I got is like below as expected.

```
"http://localhost/api/v1?param1=&param2=12345"
```

When one of these query params is null, I do not want that parameter key be part of url at all. So how can I dynamically construct URL when a parameter is null. I expect something like this:

```
"http://localhost/api/v1?param2=12345"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dynamically remove empty query parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66535069/how-to-dynamically-remove-empty-query-parameters)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you may want to use [`UriComponentsBuilder::queryParamIfPresent`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html#queryParamIfPresent-java.lang.String-java.util.Optional-) instead of the function you're currently using.

From the official documentation:

> This function will add a query parameter if its value is not `Optional::empty`. If it's empty, the parameter won't be added at all.

To turn your `null` into an `Optional`, use `Optional::ofNullable`.

Code sample:

```java
UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(BASE)
    .pathSegment("api")
    .pathSegment("v1")
    .queryParamIfPresent("param1", Optional.ofNullable(userId)) // UserId is null
    .queryParamIfPresent("param2", Optional.ofNullable(productId)) // ProductId 12345
    .build()
    .toUriString();
```

This will result in a URI without `param1` in its query string.
However, `param2` will be added to the query string as that one's not empty.

Hope this helps you out.

Cheers!

-T